# How to take an input with comma as the ending factor?

Tags: c, input

[image]

Input is like the image above. We have to take the input and add it in an array until there is no comma on the end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at `strtok`? Another way is to iterate over all the characters and call `atoi` just after a `,` until you reach `EOF`

Comment: So what is coming after the last digit? A newline? An `EOF`? What if there is a comma and then a newline?

Comment: If you are using `scanf` to read and process the input, you could use the format string `"%d"` for the first call (assuming the corresponding variable parameter has type `int *` - adjust the format string accordingly if the type is something else), and the format string `",%d"` for subsequent calls (ditto). The end is reached when `scanf` returns a value less than 1.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing or translation service. 
 We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself 
 and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, 
 include the relevant portions of your code (and any original code) in the form of a 
 [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
 and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you type the given line `2,3,4,5,6` and press enter to take input, you can easily take input with comma as ending factor with the help of `fgets()` and `strtok()` functions.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main(){
    char buffer[512];
    fgets(buffer, 512, stdin);

    int arr[MAX_SIZE], index=0;

    char* temp = strtok(buffer, ",\n");
    while(temp!=NULL){
      int x = atoi(temp);
      arr[index]=x;
      index++;
      temp = strtok(NULL,",\n");
    }

    printf("The output is:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<index; i++) printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

[How strtok() function works](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/splitting-a-string-using-strtok-in-c)

[How fgets() function works](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fgets-gets-c-language/)